# how to move a label id down a few spaces

Tags: css

I am trying to style a particular label with an `id` but not sure if the following code is correct though as nothing is changing.

I am trying to move the label id down a few spaces and am trying to use the positioning for this but can't seem to get it moving.

From my understanding, I think that you can give an id for the label correct?

```css
div.changepassword #temporary_password label {
  color: #008000;
  font-size: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="changepassword">
    <h2>Update your password here!</h2>
    <form class="signup-form" action="changepassword2.php" method="POST">
      <br></br>
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_uid" placeholder="Username">
      <br></br>
      <label id="temporary_password">Temporary Password</label>
      <br></br>
      <div class="changepassword2">
        <input type="text" name="temporary_password" placeholder="token">
        <br></br>
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <br></br>
        <label>Confirm New Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        <br></br>

        <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Password</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need temporary_password label or all label

Comment: The main reason why nothing is changes is because your selector hits nothing as it searches for a label element within this per id hit element  (#temporary_password). If you want to style that particular label, just use #temporary_password as the selector

Answer (score 0):

add this code

**CSS**

```
    div.changepassword  label#temporary_password {
   color:#008000;
   font-size: 1em;
   white-space: nowrap;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0em;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I thought that the label should go after #temporary_password??

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space from bottom of `#temporary_password` label by removing extra `br` tags from bottom. Though if its required by your design please find my solution below:

```css
 div.changepassword label#temporary_password {
   position:absolute;
   margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" 
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="changepassword">
        <h2>Update your password here!</h2>
<form class="signup-form" action="changepassword2.php" method="POST">
   <br></br>
   <label>Username</label>
   <input type="text" name="user_uid" placeholder="Username"> 
   <br></br>
   <label id="temporary_password">Temporary Password</label>
   <br></br>
   <div class="changepassword2">
   <input type="text" name="temporary_password" placeholder="token">
   <br></br>
   <label>New Password</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">   
   <br></br>
   <label>Confirm New Password</label>
   <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
   <br></br>

   <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Password</button>
   </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work but for some strange reason, I can only get it to work without using the label tag....

Comment: It would be just... div changepassword #temporary_password {}'

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, if you put a hash (#) in front of an identifier in css that means look for the element with this ID. So the `div.changepassword` part is superfluous.

When you use `#temporary_password` it targets directly the element with that id. But because you have `#temporary_password label` it targets any label element *inside* the element with the id *temporary_password*.

The easiest it to just target the element that you want to style directly. But this approach is not recommended if you intend to reuse the style (id's need to be unique on the page). In that case you should work with CSS classes instead.

A good way to learn and experiment with CSS is to use the developer tools in chrome. You can test and experiment in real time without having to reload anything. Also very useful is to right click an element in the Elements view and select `Copy/Copy Selector`. This will give you a CSS selector that targets that element.